# Writing a tf broadcaster (C++) errors

Tags: ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

after adding those lines to CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(turtle_tf_broadcaster src/turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp)
target_link_libraries(turtle_tf_broadcaster ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Errors like this appeared:

```
 CMakeFiles/turtle_tf_broadcaster.dir/src/turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp.o: In function `poseCallback(boost::shared_ptr<turtlesim::Pose_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `tf::TransformBroadcaster::TransformBroadcaster()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x1b7): undefined reference to `ros::Time::now()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x1fc): undefined reference to `tf::TransformBroadcaster::sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform const&)'
CMakeFiles/turtle_tf_broadcaster.dir/src/turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp.o: In function `main':
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x322): undefined reference to `ros::init(int&, char**, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x356): undefined reference to `ros::console::g_initialized'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x366): undefined reference to `ros::console::initialize()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x3bb): undefined reference to `ros::console::initializeLogLocation(ros::console::LogLocation*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::console::levels::Level)'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x3fc): undefined reference to `ros::console::setLogLocationLevel(ros::console::LogLocation*, ros::console::levels::Level)'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x406): undefined reference to `ros::console::checkLogLocationEnabled(ros::console::LogLocation*)'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x458): undefined reference to `ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, void*, ros::console::levels::Level, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...)'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x4bf): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > const&)'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x571): undefined reference to `ros::spin()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x585): undefined reference to `ros::Subscriber::~Subscriber()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x594): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x636): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x667): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x698): undefined reference to `ros::Subscriber::~Subscriber()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x6c0): undefined reference to `ros::Subscriber::~Subscriber()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x6d4): undefined reference to `ros::Subscriber::~Subscriber()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x6e8): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
CMakeFiles/turtle_tf_broadcaster.dir/src/turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x7b0): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x7bc): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text+0x7c8): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
CMakeFiles/turtle_tf_broadcaster.dir/src/turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp.o: In function `tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster::~TransformBroadcaster()':
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text._ZN7tf2_ros20TransformBroadcasterD2Ev[_ZN7tf2_ros20TransformBroadcasterD5Ev]+0x1b): undefined reference to `ros::Publisher::~Publisher()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text._ZN7tf2_ros20TransformBroadcasterD2Ev[_ZN7tf2_ros20TransformBroadcasterD5Ev]+0x27): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text._ZN7tf2_ros20TransformBroadcasterD2Ev[_ZN7tf2_ros20TransformBroadcasterD5Ev]+0x38): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::~NodeHandle()'
CMakeFiles/turtle_tf_broadcaster.dir/src/turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp.o: In function `ros::Subscriber ros::NodeHandle::subscribe<turtlesim::Pose_<std::allocator<void> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, void (*)(boost::shared_ptr<turtlesim::Pose_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&), ros::TransportHints const&)':
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text._ZN3ros10NodeHandle9subscribeIN9turtlesim5Pose_ISaIvEEEEENS_10SubscriberERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEjPFvRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKT_EEERKNS_14TransportHintsE[_ZN3ros10NodeHandle9subscribeIN9turtlesim5Pose_ISaIvEEEEENS_10SubscriberERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEjPFvRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKT_EEERKNS_14TransportHintsE]+0x115): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(ros::SubscribeOptions&)'
CMakeFiles/turtle_tf_broadcaster.dir/src/turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp.o: In function `ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<boost::shared_ptr<turtlesim::Pose_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, void>::deserialize(ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParams const&)':
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text._ZN3ros27SubscriptionCallbackHelperTIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN9turtlesim5Pose_ISaIvEEEEEvE11deserializeERKNS_43SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParamsE[_ZN3ros27SubscriptionCallbackHelperTIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN9turtlesim5Pose_ISaIvEEEEEvE11deserializeERKNS_43SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParamsE]+0x61): undefined reference to `ros::console::g_initialized'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text._ZN3ros27SubscriptionCallbackHelperTIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN9turtlesim5Pose_ISaIvEEEEEvE11deserializeERKNS_43SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParamsE[_ZN3ros27SubscriptionCallbackHelperTIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN9turtlesim5Pose_ISaIvEEEEEvE11deserializeERKNS_43SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParamsE]+0x71): undefined reference to `ros::console::initialize()'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text._ZN3ros27SubscriptionCallbackHelperTIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN9turtlesim5Pose_ISaIvEEEEEvE11deserializeERKNS_43SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParamsE[_ZN3ros27SubscriptionCallbackHelperTIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN9turtlesim5Pose_ISaIvEEEEEvE11deserializeERKNS_43SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParamsE]+0xba): undefined reference to `ros::console::initializeLogLocation(ros::console::LogLocation*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::console::levels::Level)'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text._ZN3ros27SubscriptionCallbackHelperTIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN9turtlesim5Pose_ISaIvEEEEEvE11deserializeERKNS_43SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParamsE[_ZN3ros27SubscriptionCallbackHelperTIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN9turtlesim5Pose_ISaIvEEEEEvE11deserializeERKNS_43SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParamsE]+0xf4): undefined reference to `ros::console::setLogLocationLevel(ros::console::LogLocation*, ros::console::levels::Level)'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text._ZN3ros27SubscriptionCallbackHelperTIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN9turtlesim5Pose_ISaIvEEEEEvE11deserializeERKNS_43SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParamsE[_ZN3ros27SubscriptionCallbackHelperTIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN9turtlesim5Pose_ISaIvEEEEEvE11deserializeERKNS_43SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParamsE]+0xfe): undefined reference to `ros::console::checkLogLocationEnabled(ros::console::LogLocation*)'
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text._ZN3ros27SubscriptionCallbackHelperTIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN9turtlesim5Pose_ISaIvEEEEEvE11deserializeERKNS_43SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParamsE[_ZN3ros27SubscriptionCallbackHelperTIRKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN9turtlesim5Pose_ISaIvEEEEEvE11deserializeERKNS_43SubscriptionCallbackHelperDeserializeParamsE]+0x175): undefined reference to `ros::console::print(ros::console::FilterBase*, void*, ros::console::levels::Level, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, ...)'
CMakeFiles/turtle_tf_broadcaster.dir/src/turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp.o: In function `void ros::serialization::Serializer<float>::read<ros::serialization::IStream>(ros::serialization::IStream&, float&)':
turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp:(.text._ZN3ros13serialization10SerializerIfE4readINS0_7IStreamEEEvRT_Rf[_ZN3ros13serialization10SerializerIfE4readINS0_7IStreamEEEvRT_Rf]+0x54): undefined reference to `ros::serialization::throwStreamOverrun()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
learning_tf/CMakeFiles/turtle_tf_broadcaster.dir/build.make:94: polecenia dla obiektu 'learning_tf/turtle_tf_broadcaster' nie powiodły się
make[2]: *** [learning_tf/turtle_tf_broadcaster] Błąd 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1523: polecenia dla obiektu 'learning_tf/CMakeFiles/turtle_tf_broadcaster.dir/all' nie powiodły się
make[1]: *** [learning_tf/CMakeFiles/turtle_tf_broadcaster.dir/all] Błąd 2
Makefile:138: polecenia dla obiektu 'all' nie powiodły się
make: *** [all] Błąd 2
```

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Thanks a lot.

---

Edit: This is the fragment of CmakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(turtle_tf_broadcaster src/turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp)
target_link_libraries(turtle_tf_broadcaster ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(learning_tf)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  tf
  turtlesim
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323315/writing-a-tf-broadcaster-(c++)-errors/) by [Kora11101](https://answers.ros.org/users/41573/kora11101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2019-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are linker errors, indicating that you don't link against (at least) the `tf` library.

Did you create the package using the command shown in the tutorial? Specifically, this:

```
catkin_create_pkg learning_tf tf roscpp rospy turtlesim
```

If you can show the `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ..)` part of your `CMakeLists.txt`, we may be able to spot what is wrong or missing.

---

Edit:

> ```
> add_executable(turtle_tf_broadcaster src/turtle_tf_broadcaster.cpp)
> ```

```
target_link_libraries(turtle_tf_broadcaster ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

> ```
> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
> ```

```
project(learning_tf)
```

> ```
> find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
> ```

```
  roscpp
  rospy
  tf
  turtlesim
)
```

This would appear to be a problem of statement *order*.

It's best not to have the `add_executable(..)` and `target_link_libraries(..)` lines at the top of your file.

Move those two lines *below* the `find_package(catkin ..)` line.

I expect things to start working then.

Finally, if you haven't yet, you may want to lookup a tutorial or two about CMake. That will make a lot of things related to build scripts and the kinds of errors you posted this question about much clearer.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kora11101](https://answers.ros.org/users/41573/kora11101/) on 2019-05-16**:
Where should tf library be located?

**Comment by [Kora11101](https://answers.ros.org/users/41573/kora11101/) on 2019-05-16**:
On page it is said that: "If everything went well, you should have a binary file called turtle_tf_broadcaster in your devel/lib/learning_tf folder."

I don't have learning_tf folder in devel/lib.

I have pkgconfig and there I have learning_tf.pc.

Is that enough?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-16**:
Could you now compile the package successfully?

**Comment by [Kora11101](https://answers.ros.org/users/41573/kora11101/) on 2019-05-16**:
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable turtle_tf_broadcaster
[100%] Built target turtle_tf_broadcaster
I guess so :)